# Scoped mutex lock

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex, raii

I never really worked with mutexes before, but i need to control access to protected resources. Looking through the new C++11 stuff, i cooked up this class:

```
class CMutex
{
public:
    class Lockable
    {
        friend class CMutex;
        std::atomic_flag flag;
    public:
        Lockable()
        {
            flag.clear();
        }
    };
private:
    Lockable * resource;
    CMutex(const CMutex &);
public:
    CMutex(Lockable * l)
    {
        resource = l;
        acquire(l);
    }
    CMutex(Lockable & l)
    {
        resource = &l;
        acquire(l);
    }
    CMutex()
        : resource(nullptr)
    {
    }
    ~CMutex()
    {
        if (resource)
            release(resource);
    }
    void acquire(Lockable * l)
    {
        if (!resource)
            resource = l;
        if (!spinLock(2000, resource))
            //explode here
            return;
    }
    void acquire(Lockable & l)
    {
        acquire(&l);
    }
private:
    void release(Lockable * l)
    {
        if (l)
            l->flag.clear();

    }
    static bool spinLock(int ms, Lockable *  bVal)
    {
        using namespace Misc;
        long start;
        int ret;
    loop:
        start = QuickTime();
        while (bVal->flag.test_and_set()) {
            if ((QuickTime() - start) > ms)
                goto time_out;
            // yield thread
            Delay(0);
        }
        // normal exitpoint
        return true;
        // deadlock occurs
    time_out:
        // handle error ...
    }
}
```

Usage like so:

```
class MyClass : public CMutex::lockable
{
    ...
    void doStuff()
    {
        // lock data
        CMutex(this);

        // do stuff
        ...

        // mutex should automagically be RAII released here
    }
    ...
};
```

First of all, I'm interested in whether this concept actually works how it should (given the implementation of std::atomic etc.)?

Secondly, I noticed that it correctly obtains the lock, however it releases it instantly. I guess i should give the lock a name?

```
CMutex lock(this);
```

However, isn't the compiler free to destruct the object before the scope is left as an optimization provided it can guarantee that i wont interact more with the object? This would defeat the purpose of this construct, if i can't guarantee that the destructor only will be called at scope exit.

Regards

Comment: `CMutex(this)` is a temporary and only lasts until the end of the full expression (i.e. up to the semicolon) then it gets destroyed. When you give it a name it becomes an automatic variable and is destroyed at the end of the scope.

Comment: There already is [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) in the Standard Library since C++11.

Comment: @Simple Yes i figured, but how about the last comment (question 3?)
-Snps I know, but i might need to extend this to platforms without c++11, this is just a prototype

Comment: @Shaggi the destructor not being called at the end of the scope, and being called earlier, would break the as-if rule because it your code can observe that. The compiler is not allowed to perform that optimisation.

Comment: @Shaggi: If you need to use pre-C++11, then you shouldn't use C++11 features. Either implement this class in terms of `std::mutex`, which will do the right thing; or call platform specific locks. Or use boost::thread. Or similar. Inventing your own locks is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @BillyONeal As said this is only a prototype. If C++11 is available, the class will use it, otherwise it will fallback on platform methods (has to be crossplatform)

Comment: @Shaggi: Then why did you implement things in terms of `std::atomic_flag`? It never makes sense to fall back to that.

Comment: @BillyONeal As far as i can see, it's guaranteed by the specification to work the i intented? Also, desire to have my own spinlock implementation.

Comment: @Shaggi: 1. I have no idea. 2. That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @BillyONeal 1. Okay. 2. Really? It gives me the possiblity to handle an error if the mutex fails to acquire the resource, possibly avoiding deadlocking the application. Secondly, it might avoid busywaiting by yielding the thread instead - this i cannot control with library implementations.

Comment: `std::mutex` can do that too. I will now mention something about a fine manual.

Comment: are you referring to mutex::try_lock? if i used that, i would have to write a wrapper around the object anyway.

Comment: Wrapper exists already as unique_lock.

Comment: Oh. Well the good thing is that this works well-defined, and if im ever going to change it, i can do it in one place :)

Comment: @Shaggi: I'm not saying that using a wrapper is a bad idea; if you want to wrap it, that's fine. I'm just saying wrap `std::mutex` rather than `std::atomic_flag`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the compiler is not free to destruct before the scope ends.

Per the C++ Standard section 12.4/10 
   — for constructed objects with automatic storage duration (3.7.3) when the block in which an object is created exit.